# Giving privilege with expiration in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, privileges

I have asked this question in `security.stackexchange.com`, but I was unable to get anything useful. So I am re-posting it here.

In parental control I can restrict the games, applications, and also set time for usage. But how can I grant some privilege (like using some application or playing games) with validity period? To be more specific, I have parental control set to an user account with all games blocked, again if I grant access to play games, it should be valid only up-to the time that I specify, and when the time expires it should roll-back to all games blocked stage.

How can I do this? Do I need any other software to do this?

Note: Down-voters please comment the reason why my question has been down-voted.

Comment: I believe a better word would be "Expiration" instead of "Validity". That or change references to "Validity" to "Validity period".

Comment: State what software you are using to enforce "parental control". If it's not complete garbage, you can probably just schedule a windows task to run commands whenever you need to alter some permissions. It's hard to say *exactly how* this can be done without knowing what software you have. The idea here is to run pc-safe-util.exe -remove-restrictions C:\games at 16:45 and allow access to games. Later, when the offspring have been sufficiently entertained, the scheduler can run pc-safe-util.exe -reapply-all-policies.

Comment: I think your question could be voted down because you don't provide enough details. Any answer will be a suggestion rather than a definitive solution. If you are using some windows feature called parental control, state that. Also, cross-posting on SE is not an encouraged practice.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин Yes I am using parental control. I know it's not a good practice, but I haven't got what I need.. And about the pc-safe-util.exe, is it a 3rd party utility?

Comment: To me, *using parental control* means parents observing children and reacting when the children do not comply with given or assumed directions, instructions or norms. If you need help with some windows feature called "parental control", state the version of windows and the version of the tool explicitly in the question. Otherwise you'll only get more comments from pedants like me and (potentially) never get a real answer. I can *guess* that you are using "windows parental control" because of "Do I need any other software to do this?", but I don't want to write an answer based on a guess.